# Downgrade magento 2.1.8 to 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1

Is there a way to downgrade from Magento 2.1.8 to 2.1.8?

I can use composer to downgrade the files. But what about the database?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily no.

You could perhaps overwrite the files in the directory with that of 2.1.7 but your DB will have been upgraded. I appreciate this may be to late, but this is why it is incredibly important to make sure you have full tested backups as this *is* your downgrade plan.

Out of interest, why do you need to downgrade/revert to the previous version?

Comment: A sneaky error where Magento 2.1.8 randomly removed "base", "small" and " "thumbnail" image roles from products. We didn't  encounter the error in test. We suspect it wouldn't have shown up in the test environment either since it was so random and apparently related to cron jobs 7 indexing had run multiple times.